# Spotlight Search does not show images from internet in macOS Ventura 13.0?

Tags: macbook-pro, spotlight, ventura

With the new release of macOS Ventura, spotlight search suppose to be show the image from an internet search. Howeveer, it does not and I could not figure out the enable it.

Is it same for you? Is there any configuration for that. Let me know.

[image]

Siri & Spotlight Configurations:
[image]

Comment: Is `Images` switched on in `System Settings | Siri & Spotlight (Search Results)` ?

Comment: @AndyGriffiths I have added the ss of my configurations. Images are already checked. Still not working